# How to make the mouse movement slower in Linux Mint Rebecca

Tags: linux-mint, 32-bit, cinnamon, mouse-cursor

How to make the mouse movement slower in Linux Mint Rebecca?

Im using Cinnamon, but cannot find if there is Settings for mouse cursor movement? I found it quite fast than normal. How to make it a lil slower?

Thanks,
Linda

Comment: It is necessary to install the package "xf86-input-synaptics" Check

Answer (score 4):

Use `xinput --list` to get the id of your device. Then call

```
xinput  --set-prop  insert_device_id_here  "Device Accel Constant Deceleration"  3
```

Adjust the last argument (`3`) until you find a value that you like. 
The higher the number, the slower your mouse movement will be.
3 seems to me to be more like the "norm". 
The value does not need to be an integer (e.g., you can use `2.5`).

Answer (score 1):

How to make the mouse movement slower in Linux Mint Rebecca

- in the lower left of the tray, click `Menu`
- in `Menu`: (all can get you to `Mouse and Trackpad`)

--either--

- type `Mouse` in the search at the top
- select `Mouse and Trackpad`

--or--

- select `System Settings` in the `Favorites` sidebar
- in `System Settings` look for the `Hardware` category
- select `Mouse and Trackpad`

--or--

- select `Preferences` in the main list
- scroll to find `Mouse and Trackpad`
- in `System Settings` look for the `Hardware` category
- select `Mouse and Trackpad`

--then--

- in `Mouse and Trackpad`
- change Pointer Speed
- Acceleration `Slow` (slider to full **LEFT**)
- Sensitivity `High` (slider to full **RIGHT**)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this article](http://www.ihaveapc.com/2011/01/how-to-configure-mousetracksticktouchpad-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/), here’s how to configure Mouse / Trackstick / Touchpad in Linux Mint / Ubuntu using GPointingDeviceSettings:

1. Issue the following command at the terminal –

   sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
2. After the installation is complete, click on ‘Menu>System>Preferences>Pointing devices’ to launch the utility.
3. You can now configure Mouse / Trackstick / Touchpad settings to suit your needs. Please note that this utility allows you to configure many advanced settings which are not usually available in default ‘Mouse’ configuration settings in Linux Mint / Ubuntu.

Comment: E: Package 'gpointing-device-settings' has no installation candidate :( That's on Mint 18 Cinnamon